# Legend for marker size

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, legend, scatter-plot

I'm trying to but legend for marker size in Sccater plot
there is some plot to describe what I want ( See Prediction Cost on the right )

[Plot With Legend for marker size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDGEu.jpg)

I did all what I want except show legend for the marker size 
Is there any property can solve my issue

[My plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZia6.png)

My Code

```
fig = go.Figure()    
fig.add_trace( 
                go.Scatter(
                            x=YearData,
                            y=RatingData,
                            name=Key,
                            text=textHover,
                            marker_size=SizeData,
                            hoverinfo= "text"
                          )
             )



fig.update_traces(mode='markers', marker=dict(sizemode='area', sizeref=2.*65/(40.**2), line_width=2))

fig.update_layout(  title='تقييم مستشفيات وزارة الصحة في مدينة الرياض',
                    xaxis=dict( title='عام التقييم', gridcolor='white', type='log', gridwidth=2, ),
                    yaxis=dict( title='التقييم من 5', gridcolor='white', gridwidth=2, ),
                    paper_bgcolor='rgb(243, 243, 243)',
                    plot_bgcolor='rgb(243, 243, 243)',)
fig.show()
```

thanks :)